# A "starvation-free" implementation in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, mutex, condition-variable

While using a simple mutex in and condition variable for worker threads, my program gets some rare and sporadic thread starvation errors, and I'd like to prevent this.

The following is a simple example of what I'm doing. There are 4 worker threads call "Producer"s and a main thread that calls prod.getTasks().

This code is "deadlock-free" but due to the errors, obviously not "starvation-free".

When I get a **Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=1m18s317ms137µs765ns)** error is it:

A) Because a Producer thread is sitting in a wait state for too long? (I don't think so because I believe a thread could wait an arbitrary amount of time before it's ready for use. Certainly longer than 1 min).

B) Because one of the waiting worker threads has been passed up too many times?

Basically any good tips as to help make this starvation free would be appreciated.

```
class Producer implements Runnable
{
    private static ArrayList<Task> arrTasks = new ArrayList<Task>();

    void getTasks()
    {
        Task t = getTask(); // get Tasks from a producer specific recordset.    
        synchronized (arrTasks)
        {
            arrTasks.add(t);
            arrTasks.notify();
        }
    }

    void run()
    {
        while (true) 
        {
            Task t = null;

            synchronized (arrTasks)
            {
                if (arrTasks.size() == 0)
                    arrTasks.wait();

                if (arrTasks.size() > 0)
                    t = arrTasks.remove(0);
            }

            if (t != null)
                processTask(t);

            if (mExit) 
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is not complete. What is `s_ptTasks`? Also, you `wait()` on one object and `notify()` another one. Is this ok?

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy : My bad.. I edited it.

Comment: @NathanHughes this is a simplification of the actual code, which does use guarded blocks correctly. I'm also aware that I can use a higher level service to handle concurrency. This is simply a question about starvation.

Comment: Why aren't you using a Blocking Queue? It will do the Synchronization for you and with `ArrayBlockingQueue` there is at least one with a `fair` option. (So no starvation of single consumers)

Comment: I just edited the code to more accurately represent the real code. The Worker actually process one task, then check to see if the consumers are behind and wait if they are.

Comment: Why the down vote? I still haven't head the answer to this legitimate question: why does this cause starvation. BTW, using an array was again a simplification or the real code, so -k5_'s note is appreciated, but this still works, and it's not starvation free. Why?

Comment: what thread is released is arbritary as stated in the javadoc of `wait` and `notify`. So no, you can't get a fair scheduling with them without additional work. Same is true for `synchronized`.

Comment: @k5_ Alright thanks. That answered my question. Too bad you get punished here these days for asking one.

Answer (score 0):

A producer/consumer pattern will always either starve, be overloaded, or pointless. This is not a performance patter, it is used for abstraction.

Your code can be made a lot easier if you use a [concurrent BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html), which allow to remove all your `synchronized`.

Comment: The actual implementation is neither overloaded, pointless, nor always starved. It runs every night through millions of records effectively and only once has shown starvation. I also wouldn't be surprised if the BlockingQueue also uses Guarded Blocks.